# ExpressJS middleware not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, middleware

I try to implement middleware in ExpressJS. I Run into a problem the middleware only works when I add it with app.use(mymiddleware) method. But i want to reach to separate it to specific routes.

**this is my PRroute:**

```
export = (app: any) => {

const endpoint = process.env.API_BASE + "prs";

app.post(endpoint, PR.create);

app.delete(endpoint + "/:id", PR.delete);

app.get(endpoint + "/:id", PR.getOne);

app.get(endpoint, PR.getAll);

app.put(endpoint + "/:id", PR.update);

};
```

And my goal is to work implement like this:

```
export = (app: any) => {

app.use(User.IsAdmin);

const endpoint = process.env.API_BASE + "prs";

app.post(endpoint, User.IsAdmin, PR.create);

app.delete(endpoint + "/:id", PR.delete);

app.get(endpoint + "/:id", PR.getOne);

app.get(endpoint, PR.getAll);

app.put(endpoint + "/:id", PR.update);

};
```

But it not works. becouse my express file look like this:

```
   const routesPR = require("../routes/PRroute")(app);
```

It is work if i add to app.use(User.IsAdmin) method, but its call this method before every GET/POST method.

Is there any solution to reach this without separate into different files the public and Admin routes?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I guess `endpoint` matches all routes, you want `endpoint + "/"`

Comment: process.env.API_BASE = "/", but I want for eg  POST /prs will be not reachable for anyone